# Is there a way to call pagination methods get_next_link and get_previous_link in DRF viewset?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to add additional values ​​to the pagination response in my viewset and keep the fields what already there. I was able to add count, but i can`t add next and previous urls to response, is where a way to call pagination_class methods in viewset.

```py
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        else:
            status_count = Vps.objects.all().aggregate(
                started=Count("status", filter=Q(status="started")),
                blocked=Count("status", filter=Q(status="blocked")),
                stopped=Count("status", filter=Q(status="stopped"))
            )
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            status_count["results"] = serializer.data
            return Response(status_count)

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        status_count = Vps.objects.all().aggregate(
            started=Count("status", filter=Q(status="started")),
            blocked=Count("status", filter=Q(status="blocked")),
            stopped=Count("status", filter=Q(status="stopped"))
        )
        pagination = self.pagination_class()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(data)
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', pagination.get_count(data)),
            ('next', self.pagination_class.get_next_link),
            ('previous', self.pagination_class.get_previous_link),
            ('started', status_count["started"]),
            ('blocked', status_count["blocked"]),
            ('stopped', status_count["stopped"]),
            ('results', page)
        ]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating custom pagination class

```py
class VpsLimitOffsetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        status_count = Vps.objects.all().aggregate(
            started=Count("status", filter=Q(status="started")),
            blocked=Count("status", filter=Q(status="blocked")),
            stopped=Count("status", filter=Q(status="stopped"))
        )
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.count),
            ('started', status_count["started"]),
            ('blocked', status_count["blocked"]),
            ('stopped', status_count["stopped"]),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```